# How to exclude given figure in the color fill render?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

In R ggplot2/geom_tile, how to exclude the data in 'month==6 & category==c' ?
(i mean the data not join the tile fill render, but still keep in the image)

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_data <- data.frame(month=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
category=c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),
value=c(53,20,41,32,67,120000))

plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month,y=category,fill=value))+geom_tile()+
  geom_text(color='white',aes(label=value))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c('white','yellow','orange','red'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `limits` on the fill scale. In your case, you might for example choose to fill only values between 0 and 80:

```r
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = category, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c('white', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'),
                       limits = c(0, 80))
```

[image]

Comment: that's what I want , it's great  thanks!